# Why is it ok to use a string literal to initialize an unsigned char array but not to initialize an unsigned char pointer?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have tried compiling with `gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors  -std=c89` the following code:

```
int main(){
  unsigned char a[] = "foo";
  unsigned char *b= "foo";
  unsigned char *c= ( unsigned char *) "foo";
  return 0;
}
```

Why does the second initialization raise the error `pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness`, but the other two declarations are allowed?

It seems that in the second case, implicit conversion from `char *`to `unsigned char *` is not done.

Comment: There is no "implicit conversion" from `char*` to `unsigned char*`. That's why the second one fails.

Comment: Right, and the first one is not performing that conversion, either. It is copying the char array elementwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, because the standard explicitly allows arrays of a (any) character type to be initializable with string literals ([6.7.9p14](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p14)):

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
>   character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
>   initialize the elements of the array.

while for most pointers conversions, the standard requires explicit casts ([6.5.4p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.4p3)):

> Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the
>   constraints of [6.5.16.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16.1), shall be specified by means of an explicit
>   cast.

Intuitively, because you can do:

```
unsigned char a0 = 'f', a1 = 'o', a2 = 'o';
```

or in other words, because you can initialize an integer type with a different integer type without having to cast explicitly.