# Legal to initialize uint8_t array with string literal?

Tags: c, stdint

Is it OK to initialize a `uint8_t` array from a string literal? Does it work as expected or does it mangle some bytes due to signed-unsigned conversion? (I want it to just stuff the literal's bits in there unchanged.) GCC doesn't complain with `-Wall` and it seems to work.

```
const uint8_t hello[] = "Hello World"
```

I am using an API that takes a string as `uint8_t *`. Right now I am using a cast, otherwise I would get a warning:

```
const char* hello = "Hello World\n"
HAL_UART_Transmit(uart, (uint8_t *)hello, 12, 50);
// HAL_UART_Transmit(uart, hello, 12, 50);
// would give a warning such as:
// pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 'HAL_UART_Transmit' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
```

On this platform, `char` is 8 bits and signed. Is it under that circumstance OK to use `uint8_t` instead of `char`? Please don't focus on the constness issue, the API should take `const uint8_t *` but doesn't. This API call is just the example that brought me to this question.

---

Annoyingly this question is now closed, I would like to answer it myself. Apologies for adding this info here, I don't have the permission to reopen.

All of the following work with `gcc -Wall -pedantic`, but the fourth warns about converting signed to unsigned. *The bit pattern in memory will be identical*, and if you cast such an object to `(uint8_t *)` it will have the same behavior. According to the [marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157806/why-is-it-ok-to-use-a-string-literal-to-initialize-an-unsigned-char-array-but-no), this is because you may assign string literals to any char array.

```
const char string1[] = "Hello";
const uint8_t string2[] = "Hello";
uint8_t string3[] = "Hello";
uint8_t* string4 = "Hello";
char* string5 = "Hello";
```

Of course, only the first two are recommendable, since you shouldn't attempt to modify string literals. In the concrete case above, you could either create a wrapper function/macro, or just leave the cast inside as a concession to the API and call it a day.

Comment: if you are pretty sure char is of 8 bits, there shouldn't be.

Comment: Show the function definition instead of describing what you think it is. Show the exact warning too, not "a warning".

Comment: I'd be more concerned about passing a pointer to non-mutable data to a function expecting a pointer to mutable data, and casting it off the warning charts. If `HAL_UART_Transmit` harbors no intention of modifying the data, casting to non-const is concerning.

Comment: I added the warning, although it really doesn't matter for the question (which is: can I assign a string literal to an `uint8_t *` or `unsigned char *` array instead assigning it to `char *` and casting later. The function I was trying to call which made me think about this is `HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size, uint32_t Timeout)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I agree, but the API is what it is (with non-const, but the contract is it doesn't modify the data). There are multiple places where you have to do funny casts to problems in the API design. I'm trying to make my side of the code a little bit more sane.

Comment: As uint8_t isn't required by the standard, this is in general not portable. However, since your HAL api is based on using uint8_t the driver can only be used on systems supporting uint8_t so it kind of obvious that uint8_t must exist on the system. And when it does, it's fine to initialize from a string literal like: uint8_t hello[] = "Hello World";

Comment: You ask about initializing an array and show `const uint8_t hello[] = "Hello World"`, but your later code shows `const char* hello = "Hello World\n"`, which is different.

Comment: Yes, that is the code that was originally there, that inspired this question. The reason I'm using an array is so I can use `sizeof(hello)-1`, but that is tangential to the question. (Well, it turns out not quite, one can assign string literals to `uint8_t array[]` but not to `uint8_t*`)

Answer (score 0):

C 2018 6.7.9 14 tells us “An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF–8 string literal…”

C 2018 6.2.5 15 tells us “The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the *character types*.”

C 2018 6.2.5 4 and 6.2.5 6 says there may be *extended integer types*.

There is no statement that any extended integer types are character types.

C 2018 7.20 4 tells us “For each type described herein that the implementation provides, `<stdint.h>` shall declare that typedef name…” and 7.20.1 5 tells us “When typedef names differing only in the absence or presence of the initial `u` are defined, they shall denote corresponding signed and unsigned types as described in 6.2.5…”

Therefore, a C implementation could provide an unsigned 8-bit type that is an extended integer type, not an `unsigned char`, and may define `uint8_t` to be this type, and then 6.7.9 14 does not tell us that an array of this type may be initialized by a character string literal.

If an implementation is allowing you to initialize an array of `uint8_t` with a string literal, then either it defines `uint8_t` to be an unsigned `char` or to be `unsigned char`, or it defines `uint8_t` to be an extended integer type but allows you to initialize the array as an extension to the C standard. It would be up to the C implementation to define the behavior of that extension, but I would expect it to work just as initializing for an array of character type.

(Conceivable, defining `uint8_t` to be an extended integer type and disallowing its treatment as a character type could be useful for distinguish the character types, which are allowed to alias any objects, from pure integer types, which would not allow such aliasing. This might allow the compiler to perform additional optimizations, since it would know the aliasing could not occur, or possibly to diagnose certain errors.)

The elements of a string literal have type `char` (by C 2018 5.2.1 6). C 2018 6.7.9 14 tells us that “Successive bytes of the string literal… initialize the elements of the array.” Each byte should initialize an array element in the usual way, including conversion to the destination type per C 2018 6.7.9 11. For the string you show, `"Hello World"`, the character values are all non-negative, so there is no issue in converting their `char` values to `uint8_t`. If you had negative characters in the string, they should be converted to `uint8_t` in the usual way.

(If you have octal or hexadecimal escape sequences that have values not represented in a `char`, there could be some language-lawyer weirdness in the initialization.)